# Performance difference btw ('https:' == document.location.protocol) vs (document.location.protocol == 'https:')

Tags: javascript

As the title says, is there any difference **in performance** between

```
'https:' == document.location.protocol
```

and

```
document.location.protocol == 'https:'
```

?

Comment: nope thats just developer preference. But `('https:' == document.location.protocol)` prevents accidental  typing of `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all. It just removes the possibility of you assigning a value instead of comparing it. 
Performance wise, there is no difference, since the condition stays the same, just the other way around.

Image you misstype it like this:

```
if (document.location.protocol = 'https')
```

You would assign it rather then comparing it.
I also like doing it this way. Its called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) if you are wondering.

Comment: Suggest adding "performance" to your first sentence and making the rest a side note. *(I don't see why this is downvoted.)*

Comment: Well, there is no performance change, since you dont change the condition itself at all.

Comment: Right. I'm just suggesting you focus on the performance aspect, as the rest falls into style territory.

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for accepting :) If you once get used to it, you wont want to do it in any other way again.